# Как оптимизовать разработку с service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

В своём приложении я подключил service worker.
Но при перезагрузке страницы при разработке, он не перезагружает сразу же страницу и это очень не удобно.

Есть ли возможность отключить офлайн режим пока разразрабатываешь приложение, но при этом все запросы что бы как в реальном приложении попадали во все обработчики. ?